# Wicket - Image with ContextRelativeResource

Tags: image, wicket

I have a simple problem with Image and ContextRelativeResource.

I have a DataTable and a cell with an overwritten popupateItem:

```
item.add(new ImgPanel(componentId, new ContextRelativeResource("img/erogata.png")));
```

DataTabe render a cell with a SPAN tag so I can't add an Image directly so I have to use a Panel instead.

The Panel is very simple:

```
<wicket:panel>
   <img wicket:id="status" />
</wicket:panel>
```

with this Constructor:

```
public ImgPanel(String id, ContextRelativeResource resource) {
   super(id);
   add(new Image("status", resource));
}
```

The image is correctly displayed but Wicket throw a warning about component "status" not found:

```
Could not find component 'sintTable:table:body:rows:1:cells:9:cell:status' on page
```

NOTE: This problem is raised when component is update by Ajax Calls. If component is rendered with the page, there is no exception. If component is added dinamically by Ajax, it rised.

Any Clue?

Thanks

Comment: can you show more code, especially one in popupateItem?

Comment: The code in populate item is the first line posted.

item.add(new ImgPanel(componentId, new ContextRelativeResource("img/erogata.png"))); 

item is the row model of table. componentId is the current TD's id.
There is a code to choose the image between 2 images but is futile in this analysis.

As I added in the NOTE, this problem is raised when the component is refreshed by Ajax.

Comment: what wicket version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Do not add the `Image` in the constructor, but add it in `onInitialize()`. That way it will be refreshed when the ajax call initializes all child items.

```
public ImgPanel(String id, ContextRelativeResource resource) {
   super(id);
}

@Override
protected void onInitialize() {
   add(new Image("status", resource));
}
```

**EDIT:**

Other possible problems:

- Did you add the item to the AjaxRequestTarget of the ajax call?
- Did you call addOrReplace() on the parent item?